# How to output dataframe values to an Excel file? [Python]

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

For the past few days I've been trying to do a relatively simple task but I'd always encounter some errors so I'd really appreciate some help on this. Here goes:

I have an Excel file which contains a specific column (Column F) that has a list of IDs.

What I want to do is for the program to read this excel file and allow the user to input any of the IDs they would like.

When the user types in one of the IDs, I would want the program to return a bunch IDs that contain the text that the user has inputted, and after that I'd like to export those 'bunch of IDs' to a new & separate Excel file where all the IDs would be displayed in one column but in separate rows.

Here's my code so far, I've tried using arrays and stuff but nothing seems to be working for me :/

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import xlrd
import os.path
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl as xl;
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# LOAD EXCEL TO DATAFRAME
xls = pd.ExcelFile('N:/TEST/TEST UTILIZATION/IA 2020/Dev/SCS-FT-IE-Report.xlsm')
df = pd.read_excel(xls, 'FT')

# GET USER INPUT (USE AD1852 AS EXAMPLE)
value = input("Enter a Part ID:\n")
print(f'You entered {value}\n\n')
i = 0
x = df.loc[i, "MFG Device"]
df2 = np.array(['', 'MFG Device', 'Loadboard Group','Socket Group', 'ChangeKit Group'])

for i in range(17367):
#     x = df.loc[i, "MFG Device"]

    if value in x:
         df = np.array[x]
         df2.append(df)
         i += 1
print(df2)


# create excel writer object
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('N:/TEST/TEST UTILIZATION/IA 2020/Dev/output.xlsx')
# write dataframe to excel
df2.to_excel(writer)
# save the excel
writer.save()
print('DataFrame is written successfully to Excel File.')
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing much more than you need to do.  Rather than monkeying around with xlsxwriter, [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) is your friend.

Just do

`df2.to_excel("output.xlsx")`

Comment: Yeah but i'm still getting an error that says "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_excel'" :/

Comment: Ah, I wasn’t reading closely enough. Your `df2` is an array, not a data frame, so you need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need xlsxwriter. Simply df.to_excel() would work. In your code df2 is a numpy array/ First convert it into a pandas DataFrame format a/c to the requirement (index and columns) before writing it to excel.